# Do you need to use -> when referencing hash?

Tags: perl, hash, reference

Using hashes, why do the following both work?

- `$hash{elem}`
- `$hash->{elem}`

Comment: http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference

Answer (score 9):

They don't "both work". The former is for accessing an element of a hash, and the latter is for accessing an element of a hash *reference*.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.016;

my %hash = (one => 1);

say $hash{one};
say $hash->{one};
```

Output:

```
Global symbol "$hash" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my $hash"?) at 41474678.pl line 8.
Execution of 41474678.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

The same error happens in reverse if you try to use a hash reference like a hash:

```
my $href = {one => 1};

say $href->{one};
say $href{one};
```

Output:

```
Global symbol "%href" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my %href"?) at 41474678.pl line 8.
Execution of 41474678.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

From "The Arrow Operator" in [perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#The-Arrow-Operator):

> "`->`" is an infix dereference operator, just as it is in C and C++.
>   If the right side is either a `[...]`, `{...}`, or a `(...)`
>   subscript, then the left side must be either a hard or symbolic
>   reference to an array, a hash, or a subroutine respectively. (Or
>   technically speaking, a location capable of holding a hard reference,
>   if it's an array or hash reference being used for assignment.)